# CONSTRAINT causes error, but despite this, auto_increment is incremented

Tags: postgresql

I create table so:

```
CREATE  TABLE mytable(
   name CHARACTER VARYING   CONSTRAINT exact_11char CHECK( CHAR_LENGTH(name) = 11 ) ,
   age INTEGER
)
```

Then add id `PRIMARY KEY` column

```
  ALTER TABLE mytable  ADD COLUMN  id  BIGSERIAL  PRIMARY KEY
```

Then, when trying insert in column `name` data, which character length isn't `11`, happened error from `CONSTRAINT`.

Ok, but also,  id column sequence is incremenmted on each failed attempts.

How to make so: on failed (reason CONSTRAINT) attempts, not increment `auto_inceremented` column?

postgreSQL version is: `9.2`

Comment: Search for [gapless sequence](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=postgresql+gapless+sequence&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:unofficial&client=firefox-a)

Comment: Why would you want that? A generate PK value has no meaning whatsoever so it does not matter at all what value gets generated. Save yourself a lot of trouble and just ignore this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the sequence operations are non-transactional. So there is no simple way exists in PostgreSQL to stop the increment operation on sequence when the corresponding insert fails.
Check the link to create a gapless sequences.

[Gapless Sequences for Primary Keys](http://www.varlena.com/GeneralBits/130.php)